Application Error when deploying python EchoBot to the Azure App Service via VS Code. Module not found
I am trying to deploy a Python code based on Echo Bot from Bot Framework on Azure App Service.
It looks like it isn't installing the dependency 'aiohttp'.
I already:

Put aiohttp on requirements.txt
Added SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true to App Settings.

I believe that I need to create a deployment script, but I don't know how.
I pasted below the startup log with some errors that may help to diagnose my problem:
2024-06-19T17:36:11.659660467Z    _____                               

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660293903Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660302104Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660307404Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660312304Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660317505Z         \/      \/                  \/ 

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660321805Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660325905Z 

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660330205Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660334506Z Python 3.9.18

2024-06-19T17:36:11.660338706Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted

2024-06-19T17:36:13.810554703Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.

2024-06-19T17:36:14.333770281Z Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:APP

2024-06-19T17:36:14.354694284Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:APP'

2024-06-19T17:36:14.813647468Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'

2024-06-19T17:36:14.836126760Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...

2024-06-19T17:36:14.836167062Z Build Operation ID: 3ea9efd5-76gt-4207-98jb-b4ccb93fd

2024-06-19T17:36:15.757313818Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20240501.1, Commit: f83f88d3c, ReleaseTagName: 20240501.1

2024-06-19T17:36:15.803859894Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'

2024-06-19T17:36:15.876379163Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.

2024-06-19T17:36:15.878094662Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.

2024-06-19T17:36:21.199999677Z 

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216749143Z Error: class uri 'aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker' invalid or not found: 

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216757743Z 

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216762344Z [Traceback (most recent call last):

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216766944Z   File "/opt/python/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 111, in load_class

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216771844Z     mod = importlib.import_module('.'.join(components))

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216776544Z   File "/opt/python/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216781145Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216785545Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216790645Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216806746Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216811746Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216816347Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216820647Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216825147Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216829547Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216834048Z ]

2024-06-19T17:36:21.216838248Z 

rs-app-service-98_0_9031ba9f_middleware for site rs-app-service-98 initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.

2024-06-19T17:36:36.343Z ERROR - Container rs-app-service-98_0_9031ba9f didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

2024-06-19T17:36:36.481Z INFO  - Stopping site rs-app-service-98 because it failed during startup.


The problem was that the deployment wasn't installing the libraries present on the requirements.txt file.
I solved this by configuring GitHub continuous integration for my web app. The actions file had a step that installed all dependencies present on requirements.txt.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The error report shows that aiohttp module is not found. Ensure that this module has been installed correctly.
Please check your requirements.txt file. Make sure that aiohttp is listed in your requirements.txt file and that the file is located in the root directory of your application.

As I pointed out, I already included aiohttp in requirements.txt.
